# Magento 2 Readiness Check give error after change

Tags: upgrade, admin-panel, magento-2.1.7

Magento 2.1.7 **System > Web Setup Wizard > System Upgrade**, After changes php setting its gives same error in

> Readiness Check

[image]

Current PHP version is 7.0.23 but still give 7.0.18.
following command already run.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

`memory_limit` also `768M` set in local and `1024M` in master.

[image]

No `system.log` genrate.Any thing wrong ?

Comment: Restart your local server

Comment: magento2 setup in another server I don't change any thing. so no need to restart server.

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174396/readiness-check-says-php-version-and-memory-limit-are-wrong

Comment: Not working in my case